# data structure for quick access

Tags: c, data-structures

The given data is input to an algo:
F1----    P1----    P2 ----   P3   .....

2  ---- 4 ------5 ------2.......
5 ----2-------10------1.....
1----4--------15------0......  (numbers under F1 are unique and non zero..numbers under P1,P2,P3 can be same and may be zero)

The algo chooses some numbers from F1 and gives the positions as 0,1,2 for which the numbers have to be accessed according to selected F1 number.(position 0 correspond to P1,1 to P2 and so on)
Again processing has to be done on numbers from selected positions.

I have made a data structure and attached the link to it where all the numbers in F1 will go in Part I of Portion A in sorted order and Part II of portion A will point to array consisting of numbers from P1,P2,P3 so that when number of F1 and position is selected by algo, the position can be quickly accessed and number retrieved from that position.
DS Image is in the link.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iz9nqfg8jy4iekn/DS.png

(In case the image is not accessible--the DS consist of an array of structure having two members.Member 1 stores sorted number from F1 and member 2 points to an array consisting of numbers from P1,P2,P3 corresponding to a particular number in F1)

The access time has to be reduced.That is why i have taken everything into memory and quickly access the positions through that index in the horizontal array.Using a simple 2-D would have an overhead in moving the numbers of horizontal array because the numbers of F1 have to be in sorted order in Part I.

How Can i  improve this?

Comment: What is the range of the F1 numbers? What is the range of the P1, P2, and P3 numbers? How many F1 numbers are there?

Comment: Do you have enough memory to store `(max(F1) - min(F1) + 1) x 3` values? If so, I would create a 2D array of that size, and whenever you do a lookup for some value `f1`, you retrieve the row at index `f1 - min(F1)`.

Comment: F1 numbers are positive numbers-32 bit. P1,P2,P3 are non negative numbers-32 bit. Range of F1 is upto unsigned 32 bit number..And number of P fields can also be upto unsigned 32 bit number (3 is not fixed number of P fields).It is also variable

Comment: What a compiler does with a `switch`-statement is somewhat similar. Maybe this is a point to start.